# incompatible types when returning type

Tags: c, ansi-c

I have a problem on convertToPoint functions.

```cpp
int convertToPoint(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct point p;
  int x, y;

  p.x = atoi(argv[1]);
  p.y = atoi(argv[2]);

  return p;
}
```

Expect to return a struct of type point, but receive the follow error:

error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct point’ but ‘int’ was expected
   return p;

What's the problem?

Comment: `int convertToPoint(...)` ==> `struct point convertToPoint(...)`

Comment: You have explicitly said that the function should return an `int`. Why do you expect it to work when you return something else?

Comment: @Broman You can return an instance of a local variable (i.e. its value).  What you can't return is a pointer to a local.  This is why you can't return an array, as its name is converted to a pointer, but a struct is OK.

Comment: I learned something new. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty simple problem. You say you want to return a `struct point` but your code says that the function shall return `int`.

```
int convertToPoint(
^^^
ups, shall return int
```

So simply change it to `struct point` - like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct point 
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct point convertToPoint(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct point p;
    p.x = atoi(argv[1]);
    p.y = atoi(argv[2]);
    return p;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct point p = convertToPoint(argc, argv);
    printf("%d %d\n", p.x, p.y);
}
```

That said - it's a bit strange to pass `argc` when it's not used. Either remove that function argument or use it to check that sufficient arguments was given. Like:

```
    p.x = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 0;
    p.y = (argc > 2) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 0;
```

Also notice that I removed `int x, y;` as those variables ain't used.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is you're telling the compiler you're returning an `int` with `int convertToPoint(...)`. You want to say `struct point convertToPoint(...)`

The error message you're seeing tells you this, if you know how to parse it

`error: incompatible types when returning type ‘struct point’ but ‘int’ was expected return p;`

1. `return p;` -> this is the troublesome statement as far as the compiler can tell.
2. `incompatible types when returning` -> you're returning the wrong thing, check what you're returning and what the signature is
3. `type ‘struct point’` -> this is the thing you're returning in the body
4. `but ‘int’ was expected` -> this is the value from your function signature.

Here is a complete example

```
// convert.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};


struct point convertToPoint(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct point p;
  int x, y;

  p.x = atoi(argv[1]);
  p.y = atoi(argv[2]);

  return p;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    struct point p = convertToPoint(argc, argv);
    printf("%d, %d", p.x, p.y);
}
```

Proof it works

```
~/src ❯❯❯ gcc -ansi convert.c -o convert                                                                                                                                               ✘ 139 
~/src ❯❯❯ ./convert 1 2
1, 2%
```

Finally, you can do a little refactoring to clean this up

```
// convert.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};


struct point convertToPoint(char x[], char y[]) {
  struct point p;

  p.x = atoi(x);
  p.y = atoi(y);

  return p;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //TODO: check for 2 args and print a helpful error message
    struct point p = convertToPoint(argv[0], argv[1]);
    printf("%d, %d", p.x, p.y);
}
```